# how to fix this error Array to string conversion in laravel and chartjs?

Tags: laravel, chart.js

i want to get sum men learning and women learning from learnings table and display to chart with group by province name.

Error:

```
 Array to string conversion (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\project\resources\views\chart\index.blade.php)
```

my controller

```
 $learnings =DB::table('provinces')
            ->join('learning_province','provinces.id','learning_province.province_id')
            ->join('learnings','learnings.id','learning_province.learning_id')
            ->select('title',\DB::raw('sum(men_learned + women_learned) as sum'))
            ->groupby('title')->whereYear('provinces.created_at', $year)->get();

        $title = [];
        $learning= [];
        foreach ($learnings as $key => $value) {
            $title[$key]=$value->title;
            $learning[$key]=$value->sum;
        }
        return view('home.home', compact('learning', 'title'));
```

how to display sum men and women with group by province name in this script 
my script

```
<script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById('lineChart').getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels:  [{!!$title!!}],
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# ',
                    data: [{!!$learning!!}],
                    backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd"],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

However, instead of manually calling json_encode, you may use the @json Blade directive. The @json directive accepts the same arguments as PHP's json_encode function.

Please like this json_encode in laravel blade

```
<script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById('lineChart').getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: @json($title),
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# ',
                    data: @json($learning),
                    backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd"],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: This saved my week, thank you!